# angularJS stop the $interval call after an IF condition is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to reload my models every 5000 milliseconds for which I am using the AngularJS $interval function to invoke my init () method. I want to stop reloading the models after all the values in a list are "COMPLETED" or no value in a given list is either Processing. Any Clue how to achieve this ?

```
 function DeliveriesController(deliveriesService, $interval){

    var vm = this;
    vm.defaultWorkspace = 'HOT_POT';
    vm.currentWorkspace = vm.defaultWorkspace;

    vm.priorities = [];     // priorities are based the names of each workspace.
                            // So call the workspace end point from the workspaceService
                            // to get a list of all workspace. Then assign it to the priorities.
    vm.deliveries = {};
    vm.selectTab = selectTab;
    vm.retryDelivery = retryDelivery;
    vm.removeDelivery = removeDelivery;
    vm.downloadLog = downloadLog;
    vm.getDeliveryDdex = getDeliveryDdex;
    vm.refresh = refresh;

    $interval(init, 5000);
    return init();


    /**
     * Get the list of deliveries and initialize the model
     */
    function init(){
        deliveriesService.getDeliveries(vm.currentWorkspace).then(function (responseValues){
            vm.deliveries = responseValues;
        });
    }

    function refresh(){
        init();
    }
    function selectTab(workspace){
        vm.currentWorkspace = workspace;
        init();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myInterval = $interval(init, 5000);
```

some condition is met:

```
$interval.cancel(myInterval);
```